# How to replace multiple occurrences of a pattern with sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression, replace

I use the following command to remove surrounding spaces between array keys that are strings or integers in PHP files:

`sed -ri "s/\[ ([0-9]+|(\x27|\x22).*(\x27|\x22)) \]/[\1]/g" file.php`

I thought I had covered all bases but it's failing when there are multiple array brackets on the same line, So this:

`if ( $myarray[ 'id' ] == 7 && $myarray[ 'status' ] == true )`

Becomes this:

`if ( $myarray['id' ] == 7 && $myarray[ 'status'] == true )`

When it should look like this:

`if ( $myarray['id'] == 7 && $myarray['status'] == true )`

It's removing the space on the right for the first set of brackets and the space on the left for the second set.

How can I modify the command so it will replace the spaces between all array brackets on each line for the whole file?

Comment: Show sample input and your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: @Cyrus Sample input is already there....But I added what the desired output should look like

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the `.*`. If you only match every character that is not a ' or a " it will work: `sed -ri "s/\[ ([0-9]+|(\x27|\x22)[^\x27\x22]*(\x27|\x22)) \]/[\1]/g" file.php`

Even better (to take possible " or ' into account):

```
sed -ri "s/\[ ([0-9]+|(\x27|\x22)[^\2]*(\2)) \]/[\1]/g" file.php
```

Comment: To the OP: In this case, `perl -i -pe` might be more useful, since perl RE's will distinguish between "greedy" and "non-greedy" globs. You want "non-greedy" in this case. The syntax would be nearly the same: `perl -i -pe 's/\[\s+(\x27.*?\x27)\s+\]/[$1]/g'`  Or something like that.

Comment: I agree Otheus, perl would be more elegant in that case

Comment: I agree that non-greedy regular expressions are more elegant than the @Captain’s answer.  But that second answer (with the `\2`s) handles `$myarray[ "Andy's cat" ]` correctly, which `['"].*?['"]` will not.

Comment: You can do the same thing in perl: `perl -i -pe 's/\[\s+((\x27|\x22).*?$2)\s+\]/[$1]/g'`

Comment: @G-Man Andy's cat...that made me laugh